# Oracle Data Integrator(ODI) Error Handling

Tags: etl, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-warehouse-builder

Is there any error handling mechanism in ODI.
I am trying to handle a scenario where ODI can load the bad data into error table when it fails to do transform source data and insert into target table.So that process will not get stopped even if there is any change in the incoming data format.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Integration Knowledge Modules (IKMs) have an option to enable or disable Flow Control. When Flow Control is enabled, these main steps will occur :

- The data will first be inserted into a temporary table which has the same structure as the target table. These tables are prefixed by `I$_` by default
- All the conditions (constraints) defined in the model for the target datastore will be checked.
- The rows failing the conditions will be inserted in an error table with some information about the loading time, the condition which has been broken and all the data of the row. These tables are prefixed by `E$_`.
- The rows passing the conditions will be inserted/updated in the target table.

Needless to say, enabling Flow Control will affect the performance of your loading as there is an extra insert and some conditions checks. But if catching data quality issues is needed, it's a great feature which is easy to implement.

Comment: Addition to what JeromeFr said: you can also specify at what condition the interface would throw an error. In control tab there is a text box with label "Maximum number of errors allowed" with a percentage checkbox. Here you can set a number of erroneous rows before stopping the interface or percent of the erroneous rows in total rows.

Comment: If the target column is expecting a number and if it receives a character ,is it possible to store that in error table .I ask because error table will have same structure as target table so if the target table column is defined as number then how can we track the rows with character values.

Comment: That would be a bit more tricky. I see two solutions for it.
You can alter the E$_ table in the database after it's created in the first run and you set as VARCHAR2(4000) for instance. Then in your model you add a Check Condition on that column in the target datastore. The condition would check that there are only digits in the varchar with something like `REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$')`. You can also add dots or commas if needed.
Another option would be to catch that kind of data quality issues yourself in the mapping and use a Split component to load an error table you manually created.

Comment: if i have 10 records in source and 1 record is causing constraints violation . Instead of loading 9 records in target table and 1 in error table any possibility we can fail the mapping exeution.